# Android Native Debugging in Android Studio 2.3.1.Somethign changed?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-debug

Has the settings been changed in the Android Studio 2.3.1?

I see the Hybrid option is no more and there is new Option Dual.

[image]

I was able to debug the native portion using the same setting in the **Android Studio 2.2.2** .
I have already installed the LLDB.CMAKE and exported the symbols in the Application Debugger .

Also in the build.gradle I have added the below lines :

```
debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
        }
```

Is there any extra change required in **AS 2.3.1**?